# PHP Regex replace tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a piece of text that contains:

```
[shipping_address]
<p><b>#shipping_title#</b></p>
<p>#shipping_name#<br>
  #shipping_streetNrBox#<br>
  #shipping_zipcode# #shipping_city#<br>
  #shipping_country#<br>
</p>
[/shipping_address]
```

In php if a certain if statements return true, I want to remove the entire block (including [shipping_address][/shipping_address]). I am using a  preg_replace but I need some help with the code.

```
$content = preg_replace("\[shipping_address\](.*?)\[/shipping_address\]", "" , $content);
```

does not do the trick, can someone help me out please.

Comment: Could you put in the question how you're using `preg_replace`? It seems that you're not using the delimiters.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to write your own templating engine. May I recommend using one that already exists (Smarty, Mustache, Twig...). No point re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the stuff:

```
$sData = preg_replace('/\[shipping_address\](.*?)\[\/shipping_address\]/si', '', $sData);
```

-be aware about using pattern delimiters and multiline replacement (`s` [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) - in this case, it refers to `.` (dot) symbol). I've also added `i` modifier to make replacement case-insensitive.

Comment: The multiline modifier is actually `m`, but you also need the PCRE_DOTALL modifyer `s` that will allow `.` to also match newline characters, but you included both anyway!

Comment: @cars10 yes, mistyped - added more brief explanation, thank you

Comment: This is most definitely **nitpicking**, however: you don't need to have a capture group for `(.*?)` neither do you need the `m` modifier and you could use a different delimiter to save escaping the `/` in the closing tag.

Comment: Agreed with `m` (since have no end of lines). Saved `()` as a part of OP's pattern (perhaps it's used somewhere in replacement in other places - not sure). As for `/` - it's just a habit (since using that in javascript).

Comment: I hear you with `/` habit... Do it myself all the time haha and when it is only one it doesn't make it all that much of a problem. As for `()` I see where you're coming from but remain unconvinced :P Still +1 from me as the best answer here

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Pattern Modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

**s (PCRE_DOTALL):**
If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the setting of this modifier.

```
<?php
$string = '123 [shipping_address]

<p><b>#shipping_title#</b></p>
<p>#shipping_name#<br>
  #shipping_streetNrBox#<br>
  #shipping_zipcode# #shipping_city#<br>
  #shipping_country#<br>
</p>
[/shipping_address] test';


var_dump( preg_replace('/\[shipping_address\].*\[\/shipping_address\]/s', '', $string ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
preg_replace('/([shipping_address[^>]*])(.*?)([\/shipping_address])/i', '', $string);
```

If you want to remove the shippingaddress too: then try this

```
preg_replace('/[shipping_address[^>]*].*?[\/shipping_address]/i', '', $string);
```

Comment: This will not work since by default, `.` does not include line breaks. You need to add `s` modifier

Comment: This is not an answer... It will not work and there are a number of different things wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

It should work for you:

```
$content = preg_replace("/\[shipping_address\](.*[\n\r].*)*\[/shipping_address\]/", "" , $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$search = "/\[shipping_address\](.*?)\[\/shipping_address]/s";
$replace = " ";
$string = "[shipping_address]
<p><b>#shipping_title#</b></p>
<p>#shipping_name#<br>
  #shipping_streetNrBox#<br>
  #shipping_zipcode# #shipping_city#<br>
  #shipping_country#<br>
</p>
[/shipping_address]";
echo preg_replace($search,$replace,$string);
```